# Is it worth my time to cut bamboo?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I was out flying around Skyloft when I discovered the bamboo cutting challenge.  At first, the proprietor said I needed to get 15 cuts.  I was able to get 17, and got 30 rupees as a reward.  He then said I should try and get 20 cuts.  He also suggested I get a longer sword, which would help me.  (I'm sure that a better sword comes later in the game.)

Do I only get rupees for completing this challenge?  Or is there something more meaningful I can earn?  What is the maximum number of cuts I'll be asked to make?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thresholds for prizes here are **15**, **20** and **28** cuts.  The highest I was able to get (with the plain **Goddess Sword** BTW) was **37** which was mostly luck I'd say.  The **Sheikah Stone** nearby mentions that **Peater** set the record at <s>[**42**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)</s> **43**.  The hardest thing about this game is that the controller isn't sensitive enough and doesn't pick up all your movements correctly which is frustrating.

It's not worth your time IMHO.  For the first level, you get **30 rupees** which is rather weak.  The next level you get some common treasure (e.g., a **Monster Horn**).  The last level you get a rarer treasure (e.g., a **Blue Bird Feather**).  You *might* be able to get something if you beat that record but I have yet to reach it myself, even with the (long) **Master Sword**.  Save it for later when you've done everything else in the game.

---

I finally managed to get **45** cuts and all I got for it was the **Goddess Plume** (another rare treasure).  Don't waste your time on this, there are other ways you can get those rare treasures.

Comment: Really? I'm finding Goddess Plumes annoyingly hard to get.

Comment: But how much do you really need?  Just through regular, thorough adventuring, I had enough plumes (and other rares) to upgrade all my items to the max without having to grind them out (with the exception of the tumbleweed, _those_ were annoying to get having to wait for them to appear).

Answer (score 4):

Cutting **vertically**, I could reliably get 20, and often 30 and above. It strips the bamboo, but doesn't move it sharply sideways, so it stays in your reach for longer.

You just "blur" the sword up and down, and don't forget to slash the stump once you're done for a few extras.

I was getting treasures like "Evil Crystal", which are otherwise impossible to get at the stage I'm at in the game (Middle of Lanayru). On the other hand, I haven't found anything to upgrade with the stuff I earned that doesn't require other stuff as well (e.g. the bug net)

Personally, I found it relaxing to slash the bamboo, but if it's annoying you, I wouldn't bother too much.

Comment: Yeah, the vertical cuts work surprisingly well.  Since most of the pieces end up on the ground anyway, it kinda makes sense (though lame at the same time).

Answer (score 3):

Thrusting is the most efficient way of getting high (40+) scores, though I've seen a video of someone swinging the Wiimote up and down fast after a vertical strike (if you have more pieces it makes more cuts thus getting 2 or 3 hits per slice).

It's the fastest minigame (under one minute), and thus the fastest and cheapest way of getting Goddess Plumes.  And Golden Skulls (Blue Feathers you could just catch yourself but still, this is more reliable).

And of course 20- 28 gets you mostly Monster Horns and some Evil Crystals.

The highest possible score is 64 - after that it skips back to 1 hit (this is because the developers cheaped out and used only 2^6 (=64) as the highest number.  I guess they figured it wouldn't be possible to hit more, but it is.

Comment: So much for the PRNG - I got only Evil Crystals (over 15) until my very last play, which netted me a Monster Horn.  Whoopee.